# Support of a Random Variable and Linear Subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: statistics, vector-spaces, system-identification

I am reading a Text about Single Index Models where a theorem is given for the identification in case all covariates are continuous. The theorem states these four conditions:

1. $G$ is differentiable and not constant on the support of $X'\beta$.
2. The components of $X$ are continuously distributed random variables that have a joint probability density function.
3. The support of $X$ is not contained in any proper linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
4. $\beta_1 = 1$.

I understand condition 1, 2 and 4 because they were explained in the text. However, I do not understand condition 3. What does this condition mean and why is it important for identification?

So far, I can only guess why it is needed. Could it be possible that this is needed in order to ensure that the support of $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^d$ as a whole?

Comment: If the support of $X$ is a proper linear subspace of $\mathbb R^d$, then the components of $X$ do not enjoy a $d$-dimensional joint probability density function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Why not posting it as proper answer? Further, could you give me a reference to a proof of your statement? And a last question: Doesn't condition 2 imply condition 3?

Comment: I don't know anything about Single Index models, and I don't know what $G$ and $\beta$ are. So, a comment suffices. I am sure someone a lot more knowledgeable will come along soon and give a complete answer.